# Como funcionam os istreams de uma string?

Tags: c++, string, alocação

Para pegar uma `std::string`, são necessários ponteiros do tipo `char`, pelo que eu saiba. Porém, para pegar um ponteiro, você tem que alocar a memória (necessariamente, ou haverá um `runtime error`, um `Segmentation Fault`).
Porém, ela pode conter muitos dados ou poucos dados; tudo depende do usuário/arquivo. Como fuciona a alocação dinâmica de memória de uma `std::string`?

Simplificando: em um `std::istream`, só há como saber o tamanho dos dados a serem alocados **depois** do *input*. Como a `std::string` aloca o espaço necessário, sem sabê-lo e sem usar memória desnecessária?

Exemplo:

```
friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& ifs, std::string str)
{
    char* dados; //Como eles serão alocados?
    ifs >> dados;
    str = dados;
}
```

Comment: `char* dados; ifs >> datos;` Isso está errado! O operator>> com char* espera que você tenha já memória alocada com tamanho suficiente no ponteiro. Do jeito que está é undefined behaviour.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal é claro que está! Essa não é minha dúvida e não foi o que eu comentei? Eu quero saber como ele aloca a memória ocupar o buffer inteiro. Se fosse assim, não poderíamos usar threads com, por exemplo, uma string e um arquivo e outro com uma string e std::cin. Também aconselho a deletar a resposta

Comment: -1. A pergunta **não** está clara. Eu ainda não entendi qual é a questão. Se é ler a string de uma stream, o buffer é alocado com um tamanho inicial e vai crescendo conforme for necessário até que tudo tenha sido lido. O que threads têm haver com isso? (A resposta já está deletada a meia hora.)

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal re-editei. Veja "simplificando".

Comment: @LucasHenrique acho que a pergunta que você quer fazer é `"como um std::istream gerencia a alocação de memória quando está fazendo a entrada de um std::string?"` e a resposta, conforme eu coloquei abaixo, é `"usa std::string::push_back (ou std::back_insert_iterator, que dá na mesma), o qual fará a realocação do buffer interno da string quando for necessário para que caibam mais caracteres"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simples -- o operador é implementado mais ou menos assim (simplificando muuuito!):

```
istream& operator>>(istream& input, string& s) {
   char c;
   s.clear();
   while( input.get(c) && !isspace(c) )
     s.push_back(c);
   return input;
}
```

onde `push_back` se encarrega de, de tempos em tempos, realocar o buffer da `string s` para que os novos caracteres possam caber.